# Can I have multiple values.yaml files for Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Can I have multiple `values.yaml` files in a Helm chart?

Something like `mychart/templates/internalValues.yaml`, `mychart/templates/customSettings.yaml`, etc?

Accessing properties in a `values.yaml` file can be done by `{{ .Values.property1 }}`.
How would I reference the properties in these custom `values.yaml` files?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Helm by default will only use the `values.yaml` file in the root directory of your chart.

You can ask it to load additional values files when you install. For instance, if you have any settings that point to different databases in different environments:

```
helm install . -f values.production.yaml
```

You could also get a similar effect by bundling additional settings as a file, and [asking Helm to read the bundled file](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/).  Helm provides an [undocumented fromYaml template function](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/9b42702a4bced339ff424a78ad68dd6be6e1a80a/pkg/engine/funcs.go#L53) which can parse the file, so in principle you can do something like

```
{{- $v := $.Files.Get "more-values.yaml" | fromYaml }}
foo: {{ $v.bar }}
```

Comment: Specifically, this is what worked for me:
{{- $v := (.Files.Get "internalvalues.yaml") | fromYaml }}

Comment: Also, I put my file directly under the chart directory.

Comment: Woud this be the case if you wanted to run two version of the application?  For instance, say I wanted to launch two instances of an nginx container, but one displayed "hello" and the other displayed "Hola", using two different values files inside the same chart, could you launch "nginx1" and nginx2" with two different values?

Comment: @JamesIsaac where did you put that snippet? In my use case I am writing an umbrella chart but I don't want to put all the config for all the subcharts in the same values.yaml.

Comment: I used it for a single helm chart and not an umbrella helm chart. I had placed the snippet at the top of the yaml file.

Comment: `{{- $v := $.Files.Get "more-values.yaml" | fromYaml }}
foo: {{ $v.bar }}` where to write this in deployment or where ?

Comment: @DavidHam how did you solve the problem of umbrella chart?

Comment: i'm trying to apply it like so, but my configuration has nested yaml inside:
```
config: |
  {{- $v := $.Files.Get "config.yaml" | fromYaml }}
  {{- range $key, $value := $v.config }}
  {{ $key }} = {{ tpl $value $ }}
  {{- end }}
```

Answer (score 153):

Yes, it's possible to have multiple values files with Helm.  Just use the **`--values`** flag (or **`-f`**).

Example:

```
helm install ./path --values ./internalValues.yaml --values ./customSettings.yaml
```

You can also pass in a single value using **`--set`**.

Example:

```
helm install ./path --set username=ADMIN --set password=${PASSWORD}
```

---

*[From the official documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/#synopsis):*

> You can specify the '--values'/'-f' flag multiple times. The priority will be given to the last (right-most) file specified.

> You can specify the '--set' flag multiple times. The priority will be given to the last (right-most) set specified.

*(Thanks to [Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5505583/seth) for the updated docs link)*

Comment: Just wanted to note that specifying multiple value files does not merge values which are present in these files which was discussed here: [Helm should preform deep merge on multiple values files](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3486)

Comment: @EthanStrider is this still the case? I just tried it and it does merge all the values from multiple values files. I have values.yaml and values-dev.yaml and the end result has all the variables from both files with the last specified file overriding the values from the first file. Simple example from official docs
https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/

Answer (score 10):

Just to update : As per the current [official documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/) `--set` & `--values` will not be merged

> To override values in a chart, use either the '--values' flag and pass in a file or use the '--set' flag and pass configuration from the command line, to force a string value use '--set-string'. In case a value is large and therefore you want not to use neither '--values' nor '--set', use '--set-file' to read the single large value from file.

Also :

> You can specify the '--values'/'-f' flag multiple times. The priority will be given to the last (right-most) file specified.

Comment: I just tried it and it DOES merge all the values-*.yaml files that I specify. Try it too from the official docs. 
https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/

Comment: The docs don't state that files will not be merged. Instead the second part you cited has another sentence after it that makes it more clear:

"For example, if both myvalues.yaml and override.yaml contained a key called 'Test', the value set in override.yaml would take precedence"