# Helm Chart - Merge two values with different structure

Tags: kubernetes-helm

My question is similar to this question [Helm Charts with multiple lists in multiple values files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394422/helm-charts-with-multiple-lists-in-multiple-values-files) however, the change is that the value structure is different and I need a way to merge those

the chart has the following

```
 env:
   {{- toYaml .Values.env | nindent 12 }}
```

the default values.yaml file has the following

```
env:
  - name: Test
    value: "Value"
```

The custom.yaml file has the values defined as

```
env:
  - name: Test2
    value: "Value2"
```

Based on this post [Helm Charts with multiple lists in multiple values files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394422/helm-charts-with-multiple-lists-in-multiple-values-files), I am able to merge these two into a single by modifying the chart to

```
 env:
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.abc.env }}
    - name: {{ $key }}
      value: {{ $value | quote }}
    {{- end }}
```

However, this doesn't work if the default value file has a key/value that has a different format.

My requirement is that I need to insert the worker node IP into all the pod as an environment name HOST_IP. Any additional env variables in the custom.yaml must be added to this.

```
env:
  - name: HOST_IP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        apiVersion: v1
        fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

So, the final yaml must have

```
env:
  - name: HOST_IP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        apiVersion: v1
        fieldPath: status.hostIP
  - name: Test2
    value: "Value2"
```

The issue here is that when these are merged, it provides an incorrect syntax.

How can I have these two formats merged into a single so that I can add them to the template? Is there a way to merge these in helm?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
env:
  {{- range .Values.env }}
  - name: {{ .name }}
    {{- with .value }}
    value: {{ . | quote }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .valueFrom }}
    valueFrom:
      {{ . | toYaml | nindent 6 }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```